# How to solve the "Longest Common Subsequence" on spoj?

Tags: dynamic-programming

I'm getting "Time Limit exceeded" even after using the time and memory optimized dynamic programming solution having the time complexity O(n*m).

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow! I recommend you take the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
to know your way arround here (and earn your first badge also ;) ). Also to improve the chances of getting useful answers
please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and also how to create [Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

lets support `arr` is your array that holds values

```
int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);

int dp[size];
for(int i=1; i<size; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
        if (a[i]>a[j] && dp[i]<dp[j]+1) 
            dp[i] = dp[j]+1;
    }
}
```

This will fill your array and is ready to solve LIS